# can laravel route return non www url?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there way to return Laravel 5 route parameter URL without `www` in start?

I know it works and return full URL with `www`
but I want to use this in Laravel 5 and it return `non www` URL

```
route('routeName', ['id' => 1]); // return with www
```

Comment: Do you want this behavior only for a specific route or for all routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not about your route. you need to edit your .htcaccess file like below

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on ^www.yourdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```